# What is the word for "fear of heights"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phobias

I know it must be some kind of of phobia, but can anyone tell me what it is?

Comment: This is easy to search on Google. VTC.

Comment: This type of question is pointless. VTC.

Comment: Zero-effort question. VTC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Acrophobia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrophobia)

> an extreme or irrational fear or phobia of heights, especially when one is not particularly high up.

*Wikipedia*

Comment: @C_P: Don't forget to mark this answer as correct!